# how to change <meter> values?

Tags: javascript, html, meter

I'm a beginner at HTML, and while learning about HTML5 I've found a cool tool, the `<meter>`. However, it won't update; it's there as a static value!

My question is simple: how do I use the length of a `<textarea>` to change the color of `<meter>`, so that the user will, for example, see red when he reaches 160 characters (the maximum value)?  In other words, count the `<textarea>` characters, and send them to the value of the meter tag.

Comment: Since you are using the (very new) meter element, it's likely best to use an [oninput](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-apis.html#common-event-behaviors) listener. Note that support for both the meter element and input event is only reliable in very recent browsers (e.g. IE 10, Safari 5+, etc.).

Comment: Edit: i've added a combinaison of the solutions to get a solution that worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that not all browser will support this tag. E.g. no support by IE until IE10. http://caniuse.com/#search=meter.

Something like this should work:

HTML

```
<textarea id="sometext"></textarea>
<meter value="10" min="0" max="160" id="somemeter">2 out of 160</meter>​
```

JS

```
(function() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('sometext');
    var meter = document.getElementById('somemeter');

    var theLength = 0;

    textarea.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
        theLength = textarea.value.length;

        if (theLength > 160) {
            theLength = 160;
        }

        meter.value = theLength;
    });
})();​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RBUmQ/1/

Comment: thank you, but the value here is static (meter.value = 160) i want a variable one

Comment: document.getElementById('sometextarea').value.length

Comment: ahhhh! so the length of the textarea will be sent to the value of the meter! thank you :)

Comment: so from what i understand meter.value = document.getElementById("sometextarea")

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp 1 sec. let me update my answer and add a better demo

Comment: ah! now it gets clearer for a beginner like me, thank you again for all :)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp See my updated answer and demo. Do note however that I only have created an eventhandler for `keypress`. Others to keep in mind are: `onpaste` and `oncut`.

Comment: @PeeHaa the counter i've used the code from here http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/javascript/dynamictextareacounter.asp he used onkeyUp and onkeyDown

Comment: Consider using an *oninput* listener instead of multiple listeners for keyup/press/down, blur, paste, drop, etc.

Comment: @RobG thank you for the tip, i learn ;)
PeeHaa IE is to download Opera or Chrome (firefox is too slow with html5...)

Answer (score 2):

if you use jquery

`$("#meter_id").val($("my_text_area_id").val().length)`

at least i think .... something like that anyway

Comment: thank you but i try to avoid it, the page has not a lot of javascript code, and i dont wanna the user download extra stuff (jquery) the bandwidth here is bad

Comment: yes, i hear a lot of good thing about jquery (less code and more efficient result) but the problem is that i try to avoid a maximum javascript, so the code will be inserted in the html, so it will be only extra kilobytes to the users to download

Comment: most users have jquery cached if you link to a centrally hosted file ... and thus there is very little or no overhead ... but yeh its your call .... but it seems like you dont understand js all that well so a helper library like jquery would benifit you

Comment: yes, that what i'll do just after finishing the htl5 tutorials, am a beginner, and found in internet that html5 will free the user a little bit from javascript (form validation for example), and the first language i've learned is python, so it's a little difficult to get the transition from a dynamic typed language :p

Comment: js is dynamic typed ... most of the time (Python is my favorite)

Comment: looooool dident know that, because when i see the braces (from (underscode*2)future(underscode*2) import braces ...loooooool) and the ; and the var word, it's not a good image :p

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is write a function which counts the length of text in the textarea and sets the value of meter to that count.

Then, you need to add a listener to the textarea.
Whether it's a keyup or a keypress or whatever you decide to use.

When that event happens, fire your function.

Comment: yes, but the problem how :p i got the solution, thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

i've combined the both (inspired from them), and it worked :) , handles copy, past, and updates in real time :)

javascript:

```
var meter = document.getElementById('shower');

function textCounter(field,maxlimit) {
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
var theLength = field.value.length;
meter.value = theLength;
}
```

html

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3" cols="60" required title="vous  devez mettre une petite description" placeholder="escence, 2006, roulant 100000km, toutes  options, siege en cuir" onKeyDown="textCounter(document.formacha.description,160)" onKeyUp="textCounter(document.formacha.description, 160)"></textarea>
<meter name="shower" min="1" max="160" value="1"id="shower" low="30" high="140">afficher son etat</meter>
```